# Import CSV file with Ui form and process it - error 404

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, file-upload, ui-form

I want to create a file uploader using Ui form, upload and process it in adminpanel.

this is my Ui form code

```
        <field name="fileUploader" formElement="fileUploader">
            <settings>
                <notice translate="true">Allowed file types: csv, xls, xlsx.</notice>
                <label translate="true">File</label>
                <componentType>fileUploader</componentType>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <fileUploader>
                    <settings>
                        <allowedExtensions>csv xls xlsx</allowedExtensions>
                        <maxFileSize>10000000</maxFileSize>
                        <placeholderType>File</placeholderType>
                        <uploaderConfig>
                            <param xsi:type="string" name="url">szk_customreports/bankdifference/savemellat</param>
                        </uploaderConfig>
                    </settings>
                </fileUploader>
            </formElements>
        </field>
```

everything is ok but my save controller is not working and i'm getting 404 error. xdebug showing that it's passing data to controller correctly but execute() is not running.
this is my controller :

```
namespace SZK\CustomReports\Controller\Adminhtml\BankDifference;


use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\File\Csv;
use Magento\Framework\File\UploaderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Netweb\Mellat\Api\Data\GridInterface;
use Netweb\Mellat\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Grid\CollectionFactory as MellatCollection;
use Netweb\Mellat\Model\ResourceModel\Grid as MellatResourceModel;
use Netweb\Shamsi\Helper\Data;
//use SZK\CustomReports\Model\ResourceModel\BankDifference as BankResourceModel;
//use SZK\CustomReports\Model\ResourceModel\BankDifference\CollectionFactory as BankCollection;
use SZK\CustomReports\Model\BankDifferenceFactory as BankFactory;


class SaveMellat extends Action implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    protected $messageManager;
    protected $filesystem;
    protected $fileUploader;
    protected $csvProcessor;
    protected $mellatCollection;
    protected $mellatResourceModel;
    protected $bankFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        Csv $csvProcessor,
        MellatCollection $collectionFactory,
        MellatResourceModel $resourceModel,
//        BankResourceModel $bankResource,
//        BankCollection $bankCollection
        BankFactory $bankDifferenceFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->fileUploader = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->csvProcessor = $csvProcessor;
        $this->mellatCollection = $collectionFactory;
        $this->mellatResourceModel = $resourceModel;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
//        $this->bankResourceModel = $bankResource;
//        $this->bankCollection = $bankCollection;
        $this->bankFactory = $bankDifferenceFactory;
        $this->execute();
    }

    public function execute(): string
    {
        $file = $_FILES['docFile'];

        $this->readCsvFile($file);


    }
```

this is my router:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="szk_customreports" frontName="szk_customreports">
            <module name="SZK_CustomReports"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure you flush your cache after creating a new controller, routes are cached.

Answer (score 0):

If you created new controller then please run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

it will generate depenedency class in generated folder.

hope this helps you :)

Comment: still getting 404 error in ?isAjax=true

Comment: whats your url in network?

Comment: https://alinland.test/admin/szk_customreports/bankdifference/savemellat/?isAjax=true

Comment: this is my url in network

Comment: change this "                            <param xsi:type="string" name="url">szk_customreports/bankdifference/savemellat</param>
 to                             <param xsi:type="string" name="url">customreports/bankdifference/savemellat</param>

Comment: szk_customreports is my router id

Comment: please update controller code with namespace line and add router.xml of admin in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124903/discussion-between-gohil-rajesh-and-mahdi-alikhani).

Comment: updated my question

Comment: your route.xml exist in SZK\CustomReports\etc\adminhtml  ?? right??

Comment: yes i copied routes codes from there